# Are canvas objects in chrome expensive to make/dispose?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, v8

For simplicity of my code I'd rather create a disposable canvas for a certain task and throw it away right after i am done, than be trying to reuse/readjust one single canvas and pass it around.

Is there an authoritative source/opinion that favors one way over another?

Comment: It is much easier to use the same canvas, can not imaging why you would not prefer using the same canvas? And yes they are expensive, like images.

Comment: authoritative source is requested in the question

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I think the best source would be to profile memory pressure of your real application. It's the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to do one thing that makes your code more simple without any large bugs/performance issues, feel free to do so. This question is somewhat subjective though.

If you do plan on switching out canvases though, be weary of the js garbage collector, and make sure there are no memory leaks.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

such steps to prevent those issues would be doing some cleanup to make sure those variables are never referenced again.

```
canvas = null;
canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
```

It is however much more efficient to keep the same canvas object and resize/transform it. It doesn't require anything extra out of the garbage collector and you don't need to create an entire new object. It does depend on what you're building if you can actually see the performance.

Comment: canvas is not event in the dom (doesn't need to be) it's just `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); /* ... do thing */ return result;`